# vivado2018.3でupgrade ipをしたらエラーが起きた。

Tags: fpga, vivado

ip upgradeを実行後generate bitstreamをすると以下のエラーがおきました。

```
[Place 30-415] IO Placement failed due to overutilization. This design contains 89 I/O ports
 while the target  device: xczu3eg package: sbva484, contains only 70 available user I/O. The target device has 297 usable I/O pins of which 227 are already occupied by user-locked I/Os.
 To rectify this issue:
 1. Ensure you are targeting the correct device and package.  Select a larger device or different package if necessary.
 2. Check the top-level ports of the design to ensure the correct number of ports are specified.
 3. Consider design changes to reduce the number of I/Os necessary.
```

upgrade前にはエラーは起こりませんでした。また、blockdesignはこちらです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

更新したipはこちらになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージの内容自体は確認しましたか？「利用できるI/Oポート数に対して、割り当てようとしているI/O数が多すぎる」と出ています。

Comment: 参考: Xilinxの [AR# 58992](https://japan.xilinx.com/support/answers/58992.html)

Comment: エラーメッセージは確認しました。ただ、ipをアップグレードするとI/O portの数が増えたり減ったりするもんなんですか？始めたばっかであまり分かっていない状況です。

Comment: 別バージョンのリリースノートですが、ざっと眺めてみるとポートの追加や変更がいくつか見受けられます。 - [AR# 72242: 2019.1 Vivado IP Release Notes - All IP Change Log Information](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/72242.html)

Comment: その場合、手動でつなぎ直したりしなければいけないでしょうか？

Comment: 「更新したIP」の画面にそれぞれ "Change Log" があるので、どんな変更が含まれているのかをまず確認しましょう。もしポートになんらかの変更があった場合には、手動でマッピングし直す必要があるでしょう。

Comment: わかりました。調べてやってみます。